# SQL JOIN with negative WHERE condition

Tags: sql, join, sql-in

I have two tables Document and Label (not my real case, I am using analogy). One Document can have N Labels. When I need to select Documents that has listed labels I can do easily this

```
select D.id from document D
join label L on  D.id = L.document_id
where L.value in('label1','label2',...)
```

How to write a query where I need Documents that DO NOT have listed labels?
When I do this

```
select D.id from document D
join label L on  D.id = L.document_id
where L.value not in('label1','label2',...)
```

then it does not work. All documents having more then one label where one of those labels is in the list will be returned anyway. Becuause raws with combination of Document and those remaining labels (not listed labels) will simply match the where condition so the query will return Documents I don't want to be returned.

I am actually working on query like that in Java Spring JPA typed queries. I need to solve this case for my filtering framework. But I think it is better to resolve this problem on SQL level first.

By the way we can replace the "not in" with "!=" for simplicity. The problem is still the same.

Any idea for a simple solution? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a `LEFT JOIN` where you select all the unmatched rows:

```
select D.id 
from document D left join label L 
on D.id = L.document_id and L.value in('label1','label2',...)
where L.document_id is null
```

or with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select D.id from document D 
where not exists (
  select 1 from label L
  where L.document_id = D.id and L.value in('label1','label2',...)
)
```

or with `NOT IN`:

```
select id from document
where id not in (
  select document_id from label 
  where value in('label1','label2',...)
)
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2f1f29a452162f1b42cb1413e7b4cead).

Comment: I think only NOT IN option is correct. The first 2 can return the unwanted ID. One ID can have label1, label2 but also label3. Because of the label3 the ID will be returned but it actually should not be returned.

Comment: If a document_id in the table `label` has any of the values ('label1','label2',...) then `exists` will return `true` and  `not exists` will return `false` and that id will not be in the results. Same applies for the LEFT JOIN.

Comment: true, I "recompiled" it now again.. my bad, I misunderstood the first two, I was too influenced with the `NOT IN` solution :)

Comment: Done. The last issue I have is that I don't know how to do this in JPA Criteria API. But it is different topic

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for documents with no labels you need an outer join

```
select D.id 
from document D
left join label L on  D.id = L.document_id
where L.value is null
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to receive docs that don't have any of the given labels, then you can exclude the ids you would get with the positive query you already have by using `not in`.
In case you want to exclude some labels while searching for others, you can combine both by using:

```
    where id not in (
      select D.id from document D
      join label L on  D.id = L.document_id
      where L.value in('label1', ...)
    ) and id in (
      select D.id from document D
      join label L on  D.id = L.document_id
      where L.value in('label2', ...)
    )
```