# JPA Criteria API - joining ElementCollection with WHERE condition on ElementCollection foreign key

Tags: java, jpa, join, criteria-api

I have an entity Document and enum Label (not my real case, I am using analogy). The Document can have set of Labels.
The mapping of labels is following:

```
@Entity
public class Document {
    ...

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "labels")
    private Set<Label> labels = new HashSet<>();

    ...
}
```

It means labels are mapped into separated table with two columns (document_id, value) but in Java it is just enum

I need to select Documents that DO NOT have any of listed labels.
In SQL it looks like this:

```
select D.id 
from document D left join label L 
on D.id = L.document_id and L.value in('label1','label2',...)
where L.document_id is null
```

But I don't know how to write it in JPA Criteria API. I don't know how to express the foreign key in labels table. The JPA predicate should be something like this

```
CriteriaBuilder cd = ...
SetJoin<Object, Object> labelsJoin = root.joinSet("labels", JoinType.LEFT);
cb.and(labelsJoin .in("label1","label2"), cb.isNull(...???...)));
```

[Here is my related SQL question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60822129/sql-join-with-negative-where-condition)

Thanks in advance for your suggestions. 
Lukas

Comment: Initially you should provide valid mapping. `@ElementCollection` is not supposed to be used with Set of entities. Opt for `@OneToMany` or `ManyToMany`. Otherwise you have to change labels to `Set<String>`. More info here https://www.callicoder.com/hibernate-spring-boot-jpa-element-collection-demo/

Comment: Label is java enum so mapping is correct. I am sorry I haven't mentioned it clearly. Now my description is fixed and more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should return expected result, but query statement is a bit different

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Document> query = cb.createQuery(Document.class);
Root<Document> root = query.from(Document.class);

Subquery<Long> subquery = query.subquery(Long.class);
Root<Document> subRoot = subquery.from(Document.class);
Join<Document, Label> label = subRoot.join("labels", JoinType.INNER);

List<Label> labels = Arrays.asList(Label.LABEL_1, Label.LABEL_2);
subquery.select(subRoot.get("id")).where(
    cb.equal(root.get("id"), subRoot.get("id")), 
    label.in(labels)
);

query.select(root).where(cb.exists(subquery).not());

List<Document> result = entityManager.creteQuery(query).getResultList();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This solution works. I have additional question. I have built a framework that maps url query params on JPA query predicates that I am using. I am able to extract predicate from your solution using like this query.select(root).where(cb.exists(subquery).not()).getRestriction() so I reached the goal I needed. However ... any ideas how to build the predicate easier way without those subqueries?  Maybe I am asking too much but wanted at least to try. Thank you

Comment: As far as I understand you need reusable predicate? If my guess is right you can write all subqueries you need inside `Specification`. I have answered similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60551105/using-the-same-predicates-for-two-criteria-queries/60552389#60552389

Comment: Your answer from the topic you mentioned is exaclty the way my framework works. I just wanted to know if there is a way how to write simpler predicate for my case. So far the only complicated one. All other predicates are really simple lambdas ... but this one is tough.

Comment: I do not think there is much simpler way to achieve the same result

Comment: I expected that. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

You should be easily able to translate the NOT IN option

```
select *
from document
where document.id not in (
    select document_id
    from label 
    where value in ('label1', 'label2')
)
```

into criteria API

```
CriteriaQuery<Document> query = cb.createQuery(Document.class);
Root<Document> root = query.from(Document.class);
query.select(root);

Subquery<Long> subquery = query.subquery(Long.class);
Root<Document> subRoot = subquery.from(Document.class);
subquery.select(subRoot.<Long>get("id"));
Join<Document, Label> labelsJoin = subRoot.join("labels");  
subquery.where(labelsJoin.get("value").in("label1", "label2"));

query.where(cb.not(cb.in(root.get("id")).value(subquery)));
```

You might need to tweak the join between `Document` and `Label` though.

Comment: I think it is close to the solution but crashing because of  labelsJoin.get("value"). But thank you anyway